# How to keep a link underlined after it is clicked and then hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, underline

In my Javascript, I have a function that underlines a link on my header navbar when clicked on:

```
$(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a").click(function() {        
          $(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a").removeClass("active"); 
          $(this).addClass("active");          
});

.active { 
      text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

But after the link is clicked on and **hovered** over, the underline disappears and the link changes color as it normally would, due to the following CSS:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
                            color: red; /* flash */  
 }
```

I tried solving this by adding text-decoration: underline; to the above CSS, but that results in an underline ALWAYS appearing when a link is hovered over. Therefore, how would I use jQuery to, on top having it underline active links like it does above, 1. prevent the underline from disappearing after the clicked link is hovered over 2. (really similar to 1) prevent the link from changing color after clicked on and hovered over.

EDIT (what it looks like doing what it's supposed to do, thanks @amol):

```
$(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a ").click(function() {        
      $(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a ").removeClass("active"); 
      $(this).addClass("active");          
});

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
      color: #ffffff /* text color default */;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a.active,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a.active:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a.active:focus{
      color: #ffffff;
      text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
      color: red; /* flash */
}

.active { 
      text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
$(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > ul > li > a").click(function() {        
          $(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > ul > li > a").removeClass("active"); 
          $(this).addClass("active");          
});
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/5SAv5/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly. Just a quick side bar: what would I have to change in the javascript to make this happen on a double click instead of a single click.

Comment: You can use `dblclick()` function. Check this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/5SAv5/3/

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to add your ul

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > ul > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > ul > li > a:focus {
    color: red;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5SAv5/